# How does GitHub detect whether the browser has color emoji support?

Tags: html, github, emoji

When visiting GitHub using a browser without color emoji support, it loads emoji glyphs as image files.

[image: GitHub without color emoji support]

But when visiting GitHub using a browser that does have color emoji support, it lets the browser render the glyphs normally instead.

[image: GitHub with color emoji support]

How can GitHub know whether the browser supports color emoji or not?

Comment: maybe this article could help: https://blog.farrant.me/adding-emoji-support-to-any-website/

Comment: @MohsenMirhoseiniArgi Nope. I knew about that article. The solution he demonstrates ALWAYS loads the glyphs as images, even if the browser supports them.

Comment: Can you link to that page? This looks to be Hangouts.

Comment: @Someone Here's the page: https://github.com/notwaldorf/ama/issues/53 The reason the screenshot looks like Hangouts is because my operating system uses Google's emoji font (coincidentally the subject of that page!).

Comment: @JopV. So, I think you want to detect the font support...

Comment: here is the answer: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576748/how-can-i-detect-rendering-support-for-emoji-in-javascript>

Answer (score 1):

I do that like this :

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.style="height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;top:60%;background:white";
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
ctx.fillStyle ="#FFF";
ctx.font="100px Arial";
ctx.fillText('',100,100);
var d = ctx.getImageData(50, 50, 1, 1).data;
if (d[0] + d[1] + d[2] === 0) {
    //need twemoji or something else
} else {
    //nothing to do   
}
```