# Create a custom unsupported emoji

Tags: javascript, typescript, emoji

how can I create a custom emoji using javascript?

I have been asked to remove all the emoji which aren't supported by users device (I think emoji's are dependent on the device even though you are using on a web browser) so I have no way to test it even if I am able to implement it.

I came across this answer which might be helpful: [How can I detect rendering support for emoji in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576748/how-can-i-detect-rendering-support-for-emoji-in-javascript) but unfortunately my device supports all the emoji.

So I was thinking about other way round? Creating an unsupported emoji but I am not sure how to create an unsupported emoji and how to use it with javscript

I can't remove the emoji file from my device because I have also been asked to write test cases.

Comment: Emojis are currently part of Unicode Standard (https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html), so it should be accepted by the vast majority of browsers. I would ask the users to identify which browser and version are they using. That may allow you to reproduce the unsupported emojis.

Comment: _IMO_ you can have font that paints some normal glyph in place of emoji. What if instead of emoji glyph you have letter `Ž` glyph?

Comment: "Remove all the emoji not supported by user devices", but from what? I don't think my old notepad had an emoji font installed on it, so removing all emoji from everywhere is one solution. Putting a sign on the site saying "best viewed in Firefox" is another.  Can you share what level of emoji support you need to provide and on what range of devices?

Answer (score 0):

An "unsupported emoji" is just an unsupported Unicode character. Emojis are spread through various different blocks in the Unicode standard, they're not contained to a single block.

So just pick a code point that hasn't been assigned a character yet. For instance, the Dogra range (one I picked at random from here) is 0x11800-0x1184F but doesn't currently have a character assigned for 0x1184F, so the JavaScript string `"\u{1184F}"` should provide an unsupported character:

```js
document.body.textContent = "\u{1184F}";
```

For me, that shows the usual glyph I get when a character is unsupported.

---

But beware of the detection technique you linked to. Both [Roko's implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45576797/157247) and `if-emoji` don't work for me on Chrome or Firefox on Linux.

Comment: Did you try modernizr?  https://modernizr.com/ (from the same answer)

Comment: @HardikKhanna - It also says my browser doesn't support emoji.

Comment: Just to summarize,  All 3 of them didn't work for you? modernizr says that your browser doesn't support emoji but it actually does?

Comment: @HardikKhanna - All three of them didn't work for me. My browser certainly supports *some* emoji, including the one Roko used in his example. It doesn't support others. (I assume, because I see the placeholder character sometimes where people were probably using an emoji.)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to create custom emojis. Not just to draw them. It is hard to code them.
Look at this example:

```
                <html>
            <head>
            <style>
    .emojiDiv {
display: flex;
}
    </style>
            </head>
            <body>
        <div class="emojiDiv"><p>This is a youtube emoji: </p><img src="https://www.startpage.com/av/proxy-image?piurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.logo.wine%2Fa%2Flogo%2FYouTube%2FYouTube-Icon-Full-Color-Logo.wine.svg&sp=1667958250Ta2f2d8d8411fb3044a0837895e548a3b6b4178cdebfc1c9251c5990b5a3eeb80" height="30px"><p> like it? me neither!</p></div>
            </body>
        </html>
```

And, This does not give very good results, It is not clean, And the emoji is not aligned very well, Maybe you can possibly use normal emojis? Most emojis are supported on Windows, Apple, Android, MacOS, and Linux,
You can just use normal emojis like this: , Potassium