# Check whether user's system can see a particular Emoji?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, macos, fonts, emoji

Is there a way to detect with javascript, whether a user can see a certain emoji?

There are quite a few emojis on my mac, that my colleague can't see on hers, because she seems to have an older version of mac OS. I assume that similar things can happen with people who use other OS's altogether etc.

For examples, when I output the pretzel emoji:   ...my colleague just sees a three black stripes instead.

Is there a way for me to show the emoji whenever the user has it, but hide it (or show something different) whenever the end user isn't able to see it?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/45576797/9504458

Answer (score 0):

I've used Modernizr in a project before for this very problem. https://modernizr.com/

If they don't support emoji's natively you could always use an open source emoji library to prevent this from happening in the future. https://github.com/MorbZ/OpenSansEmoji